# [MongoDB]Check the field value returned via DBCursor

Tags: java, mongodb, return-value

I would like to check if a field value is equal to a certain String.

I tried this :

```
DBCursor results = coll.find();
while (results.hasNext()) {
    if ((results.next().get("name").toString()) == "sammy") {
        System.out.print("debug" + (results.next().get("nom").toString()));
    }
}
```

but it returns me nothing, i don't understand.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: could you show output of `DBCursor results = coll.find();`?

Comment: you should to compare String with `.equals` not with `==`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I compare strings in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/513832/how-do-i-compare-strings-in-java)

Comment: it returns me correctly everything in my database